# Trigger for range of longtitude and latitude

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I'm trying to setup a trigger in my SQL Server such that the inserted/updated values are within a 2 miles radius from from the designated longitude and latitude in the trigger. I've attempted to insert a record that is within the radius but the raise error is still getting triggered. How should I resolve this?

Trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Incidents_longitude_latitude_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[Incidents]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CenterLatitude DECIMAL(8,6) = 40.23069818905339
    DECLARE @CenterLongitude DECIMAL(9,6) = -77.01305981730239
    DECLARE @RadiusMiles INT = 2

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM inserted
        WHERE (6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) * COS(RADIANS(inserted.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(@CenterLongitude - inserted.Longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(inserted.Latitude)))) <= @RadiusMiles / 0.621371
    )
    BEGIN
        RETURN;
    END;
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Latitude and longitude must be within 2 miles radius from 40.23069818905339, -77.01305981730239.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK;
        RETURN;
    END;
END;
```

Insert statement

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Incidents]
           ([Category]
           ,[Description]
           ,[UserIDFK]
           ,[ReportedByPhoneNumber]
           ,[Status]
           ,[Latitude]
           ,[IncidentDate]
           ,[Longitude]
           ,[Title])
     VALUES
           ('theft'
           ,'Big guy'
           ,'1000041'
           ,'315315135135315'
           ,'New'
           ,40.232312
           ,GETDATE()
           ,-77.012422
           ,'Theft at night');
```

I've tried IF NOT and IF, both gives me the same error

Comment: Aside... Do you realize that `DECLARE @CenterLongitude DECIMAL(9,6) = -77.01305981730239` is exceeding your scale? Because there can only be six places after the decimal it only stores `-77.013060`.

Comment: @DaleK I need the trigger to prevent data that is out of the range of Latitude and Longitude to be added to the incidents table

Comment: @DaleK I want to check the record that is being updated/inserted for Latitude/Longitude to be valid, if it is not valid, rollback that update/insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the precision of your decimals to capture the values you are storing
2. Reverse your current logic, because currently you are only testing that 1 row meets your criteria, whereas I imagine you want all rows to meet the criteria. So check for a single failure rather than a single success
3. Use `THROW` instead of `RAISERROR`
4. In the success case you don't need to do anything for cleaner code
5. Use short table aliases for cleaner code
6. Don't use some magic numbers - declare all constants you need in advance

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Incidents_longitude_latitude_Trigger]
ON [dbo].[Incidents]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CenterLatitude DECIMAL(18,14) = 40.23069818905339
        , @CenterLongitude DECIMAL(18,14) = -77.01305981730239
        , @MilesConversion DECIMAL(18,14) = 0.621371
        , @RadiusMiles INT = 2;

    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Inserted i
        WHERE (
            6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) * COS(RADIANS(i.Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(@CenterLongitude - i.Longitude))
            + SIN(RADIANS(@CenterLatitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(i.Latitude)))
        )
        > @RadiusMiles / @MilesConversion
    )
    BEGIN
        THROW 51000, 'Latitude and longitude must be within 2 miles radius from 40.23069818905339, -77.01305981730239.', 1);
        ROLLBACK;
    END;
END;
```